# Open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I was studying metric spaces and after reading the definition of an open set, which is,
$\mathcal{U}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set if for every $z\in\mathcal{U}$ there exists $r>0$ such that $D(z,r)\subset\mathcal{U}$, I came up with the following doubt:

Is there any set $\mathcal{U}$ such that there exists or for all $z\in\mathcal{U}$: $D(z,r)\subset \mathcal{U} \Rightarrow  D(z,r)=\mathcal{U}$ ???

Basically what I am asking is for a set $\mathcal{U}$ where I can pick an element, $z$, such that if there exists $r>0$ where $D(z,r)\subset \mathcal{U}$ then $U$ \ $D(z,r)=\emptyset$.

Comment: In $\mathbb R^n$ with the usual euclidean metric, only the empty set has this property. Any nonempty open set is a union of balls, and every ball contains other balls as proper subsets.

Comment: I don't understand this "...that there exists or for all z..." what should exists ???

Comment: Can you precise what $D$ is ? The standard distance?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I interpreted $D(z,r)$ to mean the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $z$.

Comment: @Physor I do not mind wheter this property happens for all $z\in\mathcal{U}$ or for some $z\in\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $D(z,r)$ is exactly what Bungo wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (for all practical purposes) (for the "exists" case). For if $U\setminus D(z, r) = \emptyset$, then
$$
U \subset D(z, r)
$$
but if
$$
D(z, r) \subset U
$$
then these two equations imply that $D(z, r) = U$. But the property you cite is NOT true for a ball, so there's no such set.

The "forall" case is trivially true when $U = \emptyset$. But that's not very interesting.